# Netgear WNDR4500 listening on port 80

Tags: router, port, wan

I have a Netgear WNDR4500 that I use for my home router. I also have my own domain with a subdomain point to my IP. I happened to browse to it today and noticed the management console was listening unencrypted on port 80. I checked the settings on the router, and the management console is off.

Can someone point me in the right direction to disable this behaviour?

The only thing that seemed to work was forwarding port 80 to an IP address that is known to be unused.

Thanks

Comment: Could you actually access the management interface from the WAN side?

Comment: If you were trying from inside your LAN, it's supposed to work. Turning off the management console usually only disables access from the WAN side.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to state that it was available from the WAN side.

Answer (score 0):

On Netgear's [documentation](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR4500/WNDR4500_UM_08Jul12.pdf),  page 105 there are instructions for setting up remote management of the Netgear WNDR4500.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

...for setting up remote management...
I'm sorry but remote management is something complete different. RM let you login from outside the local LAN. It is practical only if you want to change or something in the admin WITHOUT using 192.168.1.1 - as the title tell you REMOTE administration.

Back to the question, one can administer the or redirect ports, etc in ADVANCE >> Avance setup >> Port Forwarding/Port Triggering.
I think that is what you are looking for.